# Add array to CSV column

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I've searched a lot of the answers on here and I'm having a hard time finding the answer to my specific problem.

I have a CSV with two headers. "Number of fields" and "field names". I have a variable called `$headers = @()` where I hold 66 headers from another CSV I'm importing.

I want to input `$headers` into the "field names" column in the CSV. Only option I've found so far is to

```
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Field names" -Value $headers[0]
```

I obviously need to add more than just the first value in the array to `$obj`.

Input CSV - I grab all the headers off that CSV using

```
Get-Member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'
```

I'd like to place all those headers into a new CSV with a column named "Headers". Something like this:

```
Col1 Headers
Row1 Header1
Row2 Header2
Row3 Header3
Row4 Header4
etc.
```

Comment: Obviously you could loop. `$headers | %{ Add-Member $_ }` But is there a reason you don't just keep them as powershell objects? Why move it to an array and then back to a custom object again?

Comment: I need to create a "results" csv in a completely different format than the csv I'm importing the data from. Could you explain to me how $headers | %{ Add-Member $_ } would work? Thanks!

Comment: I understand if there's a limitation I guess, but that's not a reason to do that. You can easily just pull from one, make your edits and then place them in a new object. Or just manipulate the existing one.

Comment: $headers[0] references the first object. You could take the collection $headers, pipe to a for each loop |% and add each member of headers that way. That is essentially how it works. Same as a for loop maxing at the collection size, with $headers[$i].

Comment: Are all the Field Names going to be in a single row OR one per row?  Perhaps, you should provide a sample of the end result.

Comment: @codemaker the field names will be one per row in the same column.

Comment: Will the [Number Of Fields] column value be the same value AND repeated on each row?

Comment: Please provide sample input and the desired output. Reduce `$headers` to just a couple headers for this example.

Comment: How should the elements of the array be in "Field Names" column?
(Joined with commas, or joined with spaces? If it joined with commas, how can you distinguish a comma separate the field names and a comma separate the "Number of field" column and "Field Names" column? Might the field names contain commas or doublequotes?)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Edited the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just need to export the `Name` property of the headers as a new CSV. The simplest way to achieve this is a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
... | Get-Member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' |
    Select-Object @{n='Headers';e={$_.Name}} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\headers.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: If i wanted to add multiple columns to the csv and not just a headers column how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can mix calculated and regular properties whichever way you like: `Select-Object Foo, @{n='Bar',e={...}}, Baz, ...`

Comment: the only other problem with this solution is I can't append it to an already existing CSV. Is there a simple solution for that?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-3.0) yourself.